# View not positioning correctly in landscape mode

Tags: ios, swift

I have a viewcontroller having 2views one for viewing video where a video can be played.everything works fine in portrait mode but when changed to landscape the video view occupies the entire screen.i need the activity indicator to be at the center of the view but it does not happen.Also the play pause conrols are placed in a separate view at the bottom of videoview it is also not aligned when in landscape mode.Can anyone help me out?

Comment: What code snippet you are trying?

Comment: Can you post the Screenshot of the both UI?

Comment: Post screenshots of landscape and portrait images of your app so we can help you more.